# Update user using Microsoft Graph API (PHP)

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to modify a user using Microsoft API

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$graph->createRequest('PATCH', "/users/*USER_ID*")
      ->attachBody(array("officeLocation" => $code))
      ->execute();
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.String'
```

Any suggestions what can cause this issue?

Comment: I don't see any laravel related code, I would suggest removing the `laravel` tag

Comment: What is the value of `$code`? The problem must be with this value.

Comment: $code is a string like "11b156"